# parsing a multiple json objects and store it in database

Tags: php, mysql, json

I need to parse this multiple JSON objects from the JSON file. The JSON file contains thousands of JSON objects son now I need to parse all those JSON objects so please can any one try to resolve this problem and then again I need to store all JSON data to MySQL.

```
{
  {
    "name": "Michael Bruce",
    "gender": "Male",
    "designation": "System Architect"
  },
  {
    "name": "Jennifer Winters",
    "gender": "Female",
    "designation": "Senior Programmer"
  },
  {
    "name": "Donna Fox",
    "gender": "Female",
    "designation": "Office Manager"
  },
  {
    "name": "Howard Hatfield",
    "gender": "Male",
    "designation": "Customer Support"
  }
}

{
  {
    "name": "aMichael Bruce",
    "gender": "Male",
    "designation": "System Architect"
  },
  {
    "name": "Jennifer Winters",
    "gender": "Female",
    "designation": "Senior Programmer"
  },
  {
    "name": "Donna Fox",
    "gender": "Female",
    "designation": "Office Manager"
  },
  {
    "name": "Howard Hatfield",
    "gender": "Male",
    "designation": "Customer Support"
  }
}

{
  {
    "name": "Michael Bruce",
    "gender": "Male",
    "designation": "System Architect"
  },
  {
    "name": "Jennifer Winters",
    "gender": "Female",
    "designation": "Senior Programmer"
  },
  {
    "name": "Donna Fox",
    "gender": "Female",
    "designation": "Office Manager"
  },
  {
    "name": "Howard Hatfield",
    "gender": "Male",
    "designation": "Customer Support"
  }
}
```

And my code for this.

```
<?php

$host     = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname   = "employee";
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $dbname) or die('Error in Connecting: ' . mysqli_error($con));

$st = mysqli_prepare($con, 'INSERT INTO emp(name, gender, designation) VALUES (?, ?, ?)');

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($st, 'sss', $name, $gender, $designation);

$filename = 'file3.json';
$json     = file_get_contents($filename);
$data = json_decode($json, true);

foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    if (!is_array($value)) {
        echo $key . '=>' . $value . '<br/>';
    } else {
        foreach ($value as $key => $val) {

            $name        = $key['name'];
            $gender      = $key['gender'];
            $designation = $key['designation'];
            echo $name;
            mysqli_stmt_execute($st);
        }
    }
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

The above code is works only for one JSON object suppose in my file have a multiple JSON objects then its throwing an error like.

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\jumadi\b\c\index2.php on line 25

Comment: can you edit the Jason file?

Answer (score 0):

First the json is wrong. The outer brackets must be square as this should be array.

Second, the retrieving code reads from key instead of val. It should be:

```
 $name = $val['name'];
  ... etc
```